# Building 64-bit application on 32bit Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, 64-bit

I want to make a 64 cpp application into 32bit Ubuntu. I am getting the following errors during compilation time:

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.6/i686-linux-gnu/64/bits/os_defines.h:40:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.6/i686-linux-gnu/64/bits/c++config.h:393,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.6/string:40,
                 from ./util.h:4,
                 from cb/allBalances.cpp:4:
/usr/include/features.h:324:26: fatal error: bits/predefs.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.6/i686-linux-gnu/64/bits/os_defines.h:40:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.6/i686-linux-gnu/64/bits/c++config.h:393,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.6/string:40,
                 from ./util.h:4,
                 from cb/dumpTX.cpp:4:
/usr/include/features.h:324:26: fatal error: bits/predefs.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.6/i686-linux-gnu/64/bits/os_defines.h:40:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.6/i686-linux-gnu/64/bits/c++config.h:393,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.6/string:40,
                 from ./util.h:4,
                 from cb/closure.cpp:4:
/usr/include/features.h:324:26: fatal error: bits/predefs.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
c++ -- cb/rewards.cpp
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.6/i686-linux-gnu/64/bits/os_defines.h:40:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.6/i686-linux-gnu/64/bits/c++config.h:393,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_algobase.h:60,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_tree.h:63,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.6/map:60,
                 from callback.cpp:2:
/usr/include/features.h:324:26: fatal error: bits/predefs.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
In file included from /usr/include/stdio.h:28:0,
                 from cb/help.cpp:4:
/usr/include/features.h:324:26: fatal error: bits/predefs.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [.objs/dumpTX.o] Error 1
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make: *** [.objs/allBalances.o] Error 1
make: *** [.objs/closure.o] Error 1
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.6/i686-linux-gnu/64/bits/os_defines.h:40:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.6/i686-linux-gnu/64/bits/c++config.h:393,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.6/string:40,
                 from ./util.h:4,
                 from cb/pristine.cpp:4:
/usr/include/features.h:324:26: fatal error: bits/predefs.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [.objs/callback.o] Error 1
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.6/i686-linux-gnu/64/bits/os_defines.h:40:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.6/i686-linux-gnu/64/bits/c++config.h:393,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.6/string:40,
                 from ./util.h:4,
                 from cb/rewards.cpp:4:
/usr/include/features.h:324:26: fatal error: bits/predefs.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

I guess there is a fix on that by downloading the appropriate 64b `libc` environment. Is this the case? How do I proceed?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [package index](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=precise&arch=any&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=predefs.h), `libc6-dev-amd64` contains `bits/predefs.h` (your errors are about that header file being missing). So install it:

```
sudo apt-get install libc6-dev-amd64
```

Comment: Now i am getting this: ''google/dense_hash_map: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
''

Comment: @curious the corresponding package is `libsparsehash-dev`, according to [the index](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=precise&arch=any&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=google%2Fdense_hash_map).